# Jquery fadeTo IMG SRC on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, fade

So right now I have this:

```
$('#logo').hover(
function(){
  $(this).attr('src','img/logo-hover.jpg');
},
function(){
  $(this).attr('src','img/logo-grey.jpg');
}
```

Which works, but I wanted to add a fade effect to it. I've tried several iterations of fadeTo, fadeIn, fadeOut and looked at several examples of rollovers (most of which seem overly complex for what I want to do here) but I cannot seem to get this working. All of the examples I have seen also fade out the original image before bringing in the new one which I do not need to do.

What is the cleanest way to add this effect?

To give an example using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5kb/
I would like this effect, except using 2 images instead

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)/[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) & [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) to do it

```
$('#logo').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo('normal', .1, function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '//placehold.it/64/ff0000').fadeTo('normal', 1);
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo('normal', .1, function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '//placehold.it/64/0000ff').fadeTo('normal', 1);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rpWCG/)

Comment: This works, but it fades the original out before bringing in the new one so there is a period in between where the logo disappears which is what I was trying to avoid. To give an example of what I'm trying to do with but instead using css:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5kb/

except use this same type of effect with two images

Comment: @Tyler whether the disappearing problem comes only the first time  or is coming every time? whether the images are cahced

Answer (score 0):

You could also try css-transitions, but this will probably not run on every browser

```
#logo img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;    
}

#logo1 {
    opacity: 1;
}

#logo2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

#logo:hover #logo1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

#logo:hover #logo2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TYVTb/5/